# C# How to add custom save button to 'Save As' menu in Microsoft Word

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office, vsto

I'm creating a Microsoft Word 2016 VSTO addin that allows Users to create and save a document into an Electronic Document Management System. Currently the 'Save' button is only available via the ribbon tab. I would somehow like to get it to appear in the File > Save As menu as seen below[image: Save As Menu]

Has anyone done this before? Any ideas on how I could achieve this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The area in Word 2016 you are referring to is called the Backstage View. This can be edited using XML. Microsoft has a tutorial that explains how to customize an existing Backstage View tab:

[Customizing the Office 2010 Backstage View for Developers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee815851(v=office.14).aspx)

Additional information can be found around the web including here:

[Introduction to the Office 2010 Backstage View for Developers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee691833(v=office.14).aspx)

Both of these articles cite Office 2010, but the principals and most of the specifics are still valid in Office 2016.

Comment: How to place own button/control exact below the Google drive's button?

Comment: @wacky_coder the "Introduction to the Office 2010 Backstage View for Developers" link in my post contains Visual How Tos on the page's left navigation pane. If you still need assistance after viewing those, please post the XML you are having trouble with as part of a new question.

Comment: @joeschwa gone through with you that "ntroduction to the Office 2010 Backstage View for Developers" link and did the first task. Now wondering that how to add a list of available folders in task. Which is not mentioned in that link i guess, correct me if i am wrong.